# How do I make Multithreaded Synchronization tab available in Hybris BackOffice?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I'm following this guide https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/e1d742dac110467c81ce6d6b139879e8.html right now. I'm able to enter backoffice, but the last System tab available to me is System Setup Audit.

I'd appreciate ur help

UPDATE:

https://experts.hybris.com/questions/101847/how-do-i-make-some-attribute-of-my-custom-item-typ.html

Answer (score 0):

You need roles for showing these menus. If you are using standard admin user, may be your initialization failed.